# PHP form post gives Page Not Found 404 error in Internet Explorer while Firefox and Chrome give expected results

Tags: php

I have a PHP page (search_employee.php) where I use three different hidden form input elements on three different forms to direct users where I need them to go.  The page posts back on itself for each of these submittals.

```
if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {...

} elseif (isset($_POST['bypassed'])) {...

if (isset($_POST['multicheck'])) {...

}
```

I am having a problem with Internet Explorer 8 in that when I try to submit on a post back to this same page (search_employee.php) with this form:

```
<form action="search_employee.php" method="post">
   <input type="submit" name="select" value="Select" />
   <input type="hidden" name="multicheck" value="TRUE" />
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $id . '" />
   <input type="hidden" name="eid" value="' . $row['eid'] . '" />
</form>
```

I get a Page Not Found 404 error, even though the 404 page has the exact same url as before the post, character for character.  This is after I have successfully processed the "submitted" post back multiple times (search function that users can repeat).

I have tested my code in both Firefox and Chrome, and both process the "multicheck" post back exactly as desired.  Is this something that is a known bug in IE, and is there a workaround?  I'm at a loss for where to look next since this works in FF & Chrome.

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: Have you tried to write the method in uppercase? method="POST"

Comment: No change.  Firefox still good, IE no good.

Comment: Can you check your servers access logs to see what URL it received? If you run Apache on Linux you will find them most likely in /var/log/apache2/access_log. Do you use a PHP framework and if yes which one? There are two possible causes for a 404, the URL is invalid in which cause the webserver directly returns a 404. Or your URL is valid and the webserver actually does call your script but your script decides to return a 404 (which might be hidden away in a framework). As you only have a problem with IE I suspect the URL more then your script.

Comment: @eelke unless that's an xhtml page, the method value is case-insensitive as per standard html syntax rules.

Comment: What happens if you use `action=""`?

Comment: @Marc B: Yes I know but I wouldn't trust IE to get that right as it requires xhtml to be served with an incorrect text/html mime type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like my name as a newbie is apt.  For results I was only looking in the browser address bar as I am constructing this page flow as I go.  Hence the next page in sequence, the one that 404'd in IE, doesn't exist yet.  The reason this was confusing was that the address bar in IE still showed the url for current page, not the actual missing page url, so I thought the post back wasn't working when it was actually trying to call the right page.  Both FF and Chrome show the actual url of the 404 page.  IE gave "search_employee.php", while FF and Chrome gave "add_employee.php?id=16844" as desired.  The only way I saw this though was to look at the server logs as you instructed Eelke.  Thank you and everybody else for your comments.  I appreciate it!